# How to access a remote Git repository in Jenkins using aliases?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, domain-aliasing

**short version**

I'm using aliasing to connect my remote Git repositories. It works, but when I add such repository to Jenkins, it cannot access the repository and display the error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true
>   ls-remote -h git@github.com-foo:myaccount/myrepository.git HEAD"
>   returned status code 128: stdout: stderr: ssh: Could not resolve
>   hostname github.com-foo: Name or service not known fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

---

**detailed issue description**

In order to `commit`/`push` code as different users I use aliasing:

**`C:\Users\myusername\.ssh\config`**

```
...

#github.com-foo account
Host github.com-foo
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo

#github.com-bar account
Host github.com-bar
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bar

...
```

Then instead of

```
git clone git@github.com:myaccount/myrepository.git
```

I simply use

```
git clone git@github.com-foo:myaccount/myrepository.git
```

The `.ssh` directory is accessible from my local VMs as a shared folder, so also use my credentials on the VMs as well.

Everything works.

Now I installed Jenkins on a VM and want to configure the connection to a remote repository stored on GitHub. What I did:

1. Credentials: `Jenkins -> Credentials -> [link] Global credentials (unrestricted) -> [radio button] Enter directly -> [textarea] Key -> added -> [button] Save`.
2. Git plugin: `Jenkins -> Configuration -> [section] Git plugin` -- Email and Name set up:

[image]

3. Project Git settings: `[project] -> Configuration -> [section] Source Code Management -> [section] Git` -- Repository URL and credentials:

[image]

As on the screenshot shown, the connection is failing.

**Why does it not work and how to get it working, in order to connect a remote Git repository in Jenkins using aliases?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `jenkins` the `ssh` configuration. The file

```
C:\Users\myusername\.ssh\config
```

is applicable for your user, but you need the alias also for the `jenkins` user, under which is `jenkins` running. Find home directory for `jenkins` user and add file `.ssh\config` there.

Then you also probably need to copy/create different `ssh` keys for `jenkins` in it's home directory, because, your are not accessible from `jenkins` user.

After this the file assess permissions should be set. It can be easily done by `chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`.

In the global Jenkins settings the private key can then be set to "From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't copy my SSH key to the Jenkins `.ssh` directory -- I added the key file content directly into the configs. But I found the Jenkins home folder and replaced `$JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` by a symlink to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. I also added there a symlink to the SSH `config` file: `ln -s ~/.ssh/config /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config`. Nevertheless I'm still getting the same connection error.

Comment: Symlink is probably not enough, because the `jenkins` user will probably not have a access to them.

Comment: You are right. OK, I tried this: I copied `known_hosts`, `config`, and (just in case) the key files `id_rsa_foo` and `id_rsa_foo.pub` to `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/`. After this I restarted Jenkins. But it hasn't helped -- still the same error.

Comment: `jenkins` might even ignore the ssh config. Why don't you use credentials stored in jenkins and the `github.com` hostname directly?

Comment: It works! I had to copy my private SSH key file and the SSH `config` to the Jenkins home directory. After this I got permission problem, but they have been resolved by `chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`. Thank you very much for your help!